# ActiveMq customers cannot receive messages

Tags: activemq-classic

The customers cannot get any message from the queue. The mq and customer are all running but the pending queue is larger. Restarting the customer does not help. If I restart the mq  the messages are consumed very fast, but later,the queue is still stuck.

I found a case that another queue has no customers and is rising very fast. When start customer to receive, the stuck queue is never stuck. If I clean this queue and never push message to it, the stuck messages of queue will consumed normally. Is the high load queue blocking the other queue?

In the stuck condition, the message from web console sending can be consumed, just the JmsTemplate message not. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Can you please tell if these are persistent messages? If yes then can you also give some details about what kind of persistent adapter/configuration you have setup at ActiveMQ server?

Comment: It may be something client side. I would start gather some logs (you may need to increase log level!) and low level behaviour, then analyze it and come back here. You can check that the broker actually get acks from the client.